# PyFlink java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I have a PyFlink job that reads from a file, filter based on a condition, and print. This is a `tree` view of my working directory. This is the PyFlink script main.py:

```py
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, DataTypes
from pyflink.table.udf import udf

# https://flink.apache.org/2020/04/09/pyflink-udf-support-flink.html
# https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/python/table-api-users-guide/udfs/python_udfs.html

@udf(input_types=[DataTypes.STRING()], result_type=DataTypes.MAP(DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING()))
def parse(s):
  import json
  # a dummy parser
  res = {'item_id': 123, 'tag': 'a'}
  return res

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

t_env.register_function("parse", parse)

my_source_ddl = """
create table mySource (
    id BIGINT,
    contentstr STRING
) with (
    'connector' = 'filesystem',
    'format' = 'json',
    'path' = '/tmp/input'
)
"""

my_sink_ddl = """
create table mySink (
    id BIGINT
) with (
    'connector' = 'print'
)
"""

my_transform_dml = """
insert into mySink
with t1 as (
    select id, parse(contentstr) as content
    from mySource
)
select id
from t1
where content['item_id'] is not null
and content['tag'] = 'a'
"""

t_env.execute_sql(my_source_ddl)
t_env.execute_sql(my_sink_ddl)
t_env.execute_sql(my_transform_dml).wait()
```

To run the `main.py`:

- Ensure installing pyflink==1.12.0 in my conda env
- /tmp/input has a single row of content `{"id":1,"tag":"a"}`

Then I run `main.py` and I get the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udf_parse.py", line 53, in <module>
    t_env.execute_sql(my_transform_dml).wait()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyflink-quickstart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/table/table_result.py", line 76, in wait
    get_method(self._j_table_result, "await")()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyflink-quickstart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1286, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyflink-quickstart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 147, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyflink-quickstart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.await.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.awaitInternal(TableResultImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.await(TableResultImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(TableResultImpl.java:350)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.isFirstRowReady(TableResultImpl.java:363)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.lambda$awaitInternal$1(TableResultImpl.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:54)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1046)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:447)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.StringDataSerializer.deserializeInternal(StringDataSerializer.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.StringDataSerializer.deserialize(StringDataSerializer.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.StringDataSerializer.deserialize(StringDataSerializer.java:34)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.serializers.python.MapDataSerializer.deserializeInternal(MapDataSerializer.java:129)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.serializers.python.MapDataSerializer.deserialize(MapDataSerializer.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.serializers.python.MapDataSerializer.deserialize(MapDataSerializer.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.serializers.python.RowDataSerializer.deserialize(RowDataSerializer.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.serializers.python.RowDataSerializer.deserialize(RowDataSerializer.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.scalar.RowDataPythonScalarFunctionOperator.emitResult(RowDataPythonScalarFunctionOperator.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.emitResults(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.invokeFinishBundle(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.processWatermark(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ChainingOutput.emitWatermark(ChainingOutput.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitWatermark(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask.advanceToEndOfEventTime(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask.afterInvoke(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The issue is probably related to the udf. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is:

```py
@udf(input_types=[DataTypes.STRING()], result_type=DataTypes.MAP(DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING()))
def parse(s):
  import json
  # a dummy parser
  res = {'item_id': 123, 'tag': 'a'}
  return res
```

The `result_type` is `DataTypes.MAP(DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING())`, but `item_id` has value type integer.

A fix is simple:

```py
def parse(s):
  import json
  # a dummy parser
  res = {'item_id': 123, 'tag': 'a'}
  res = {str(k): str(v) for k, v in res.items()}
  return res
```